# Cordova dialog special characters

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm using cordova's dialog plugin for the notification.confirm method. The dialog works fine, except special characters (like ç and ã) show up as question marks. What can I do about this?

I've tested on iOS7 and androd 4.0.4, both english language devices.

My html declares charset=UTF-8, the issue is only happening with this plugin.

Comment: what version of cordova? just tested iOS7/Cordova 3.2, copy pasted your chars into existing alert & confirm message strings ...they show up fine.

Comment: have you tried encoding the special characters say **&#228**

Comment: are you using this cordova-plugin-dialogs: 0.2.6 ?

Comment: Never mind, I'm stupid. The .js file from which I was launching the dialog wasn't encoded in UTF-8 (was in ANSI), changing that fixed the problem.

Comment: You should reframe your comment and post it as an answer, then tomorrow you should accept it. That way other users suffering from similar problems will benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that the file from which I was launching the dialog wasn't encoded in utf-8.
Changing that fixed the issue.